# Chrome version 32 (Mac) stops loading image from src when image is created programmatically

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, dom

Can anyone explain what's going on here? The following webpage shows three copies of a jpg when loaded in Safari and Chrome (older than version 32, released Tuesday). On new Chrome it show only the first two images; the third never gets loaded and the callback never fires.

(EDIT: while the issue here was simple, it's not quite fair to say that it is a simple typo. Many browser supported "img" as an allowable synonym for the "image" tag, and Chrome withdrew that support so pages that used to work suddenly failed without helpful error reporting. Others may find this knowledge useful.)

Sample HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>My Title></title></head>
<body>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize);

function initialize() {
    var imageURL = document.getElementById("img1").src;
    console.log(imageURL);

    var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
    img2.onload = function(){console.log("loaded image 2");};
    img2.src = imageURL;

    var img3 = document.createElement("image");
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.appendChild(img3);
    img3.onload = function(){
        // never fires in Chrome version 32
        console.log("loaded image 3");};
    img3.src = imageURL;
}
</script>
Image loaded from absolute URL<br>
<img id="img1" src="http://www.rakkup.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/rakkup-logo-for-website.png"></img>
<br>
Image created in HTML and src is set programmatically<br>
<img id="img2"><img>
<br>
<div id="container">
Image created in JavaScript and src is set programmatically<br>
Loads in Safari and Chrome before version 32, but not in Chrome 32<br>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You've got a typo, `image` should be `img`. There's no tag known as "image".

Comment: well son of a... apparently "image" used to work as a synonym for "img" until now. Nice catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `document.createElement("image")` to `document.createElement("img")`.
Some browsers like safari allow `image` as a synonym of `img`.
But as its unofficial it will not work everywhere.

Comment: RobW got there first with his comment above, but this is indeed the issue. Apparently Chrome also allowed "image" until their update this week. Thanks.